# printing substrings in a file

Tags: c, arrays, io

So I want to write a program which would print out a text line that contains a certain word from a file. e.g. if I was looking for a word 'linux' it would print out

> 2 computers called linux00, linux01 and linux02.
>
> 5 manager,"
>   said linux00. "Hello linux00,"  said
>
> 7 here to see us?" said
>   linux01. "Well," said the
>
> 10 linux02. "You're all going to be
>   unplugged," said
>
> 12 goooooooooooo..." said linux00.

from a story.txt:

> Once upon a time, there were three little
>
> computers called
>   linux00, linux01 and linux02.
>
> One day, the nice computer manager
>   came into
>
> the Linux Laboratory. "Hello nice computer
>
> manager,"
>   said linux00. "Hello linux00," said
>
> the nice computer manager.
>   "What brings you
>
> here to see us?" said linux01. "Well," said the
>
> nice computer manager, "I've got bad news and
>
> I've got good
>   news." "What's the bad news?" said
>
> linux02. "You're all going to be
>   unplugged," said
>
> the nice computer manager. "What's the
>
> goooooooooooo..." said linux00.

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ARR_LEN 100

 int getLine(FILE * fin,char a[],int n)
{
   int find = contains("linux", 5, a, ARR_LEN);
   int count;
   int i;
   i = 0;
   char c = getc(fin);
      while(c != '\n')
   {
    a[i] = c;
    // printf ("%c", a[i]);
    //i = 0;

     if (a[i] == EOF){
        return EOF;
    }

    if (find == 1)
    {
           printf("%c", c);
           c = getc(fin);

    }
    i = i + 1;
   }
    if(a[i]=='\n')
    {
           if ((i - 1) > ARR_LEN) {
        printf("warning msg: length is over array bounds\n");
     }
    // printf("length of line is: %d\n", i - 1);
    //printf("%c", a[i]);
     i = i + 1;
    //printf("\n");
    return i - 1;



   }
}
int contains(char target[], int m, char source[], int n) {
    int flag = 0; // the source originally does not contain the target
    int i;

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++) { // go through each character of the source string
    int targetIndex = 0;
    int j;
            /*check if the preceding characters of the source string are a substring
            that matches the target string*/
    for(j = i; j < n && targetIndex < m; j++) {
        if(target[targetIndex] == source[j]) {
            targetIndex += 1;
            if(targetIndex == m) { // the 'target' has been fully found
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag == 1)  // 'target' is already found, no need to search further
    {
      break;
    }
}

return flag;
}



    main(int argc,char ** argv)
{
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);
    char a[ARR_LEN];
    FILE * fin;
    if(argc<2){
      printf("wrong number of arguments\n");
      exit(0);
    }
    fin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fin == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open %s\n", fin);
    exit(0);
    }
   int t = 0;
   int j = 0;
   int find = contains("linux", 5, a, ARR_LEN);
    while (j != EOF)
{
    t = t + 1;
    printf("%d ", t);
    j = getLine(fin,a,ARR_LEN);
    printf("\n");
}
    fclose(fin);
}
```

The getLine function is alright and it prints out a text with a line number in front all good. But the problem is with this

```
if (find == 1)
    {
           printf("%c", c);
           c = getc(fin);

    }
```

part, where I want the program to only print out the line if "contains" finds a match in that line.

Thanks for any help & sorry for a long post!!

Comment: Looks like `contains("linux", 5, a, ARR_LEN);` called before `getLine(fin,a,ARR_LEN);` rather than afterwards.

Comment: if you're talking about that one in main(), I just forgot to delete it but it doesn't change anything anyways

Comment: Minor: `char c` should be `int c`.  Any test for EOF like in `if (a[i] == EOF){` should happen before assignment to `a`.  EOF is a condition, not a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int main()
    {
      char sentence[500];
      char word[10] = "linux";
      FILE* fp1 = fopen("strstr.txt","r");
      if(fp1 == NULL)
      {
         printf("Failed to open file\n");
         return 1;
      }
      while((fscanf(fp1,"%[^\n]\n",sentence)>0))
      {
          if(strstr(sentence,word)!=NULL)
          printf("%s\n\n",sentence);
      }
    }
```

Comment: I can't use strstr, cause I have to have a function contains, which returns 1 or 0, and then use it in (or with) getLine to get what I want. Thanks anyways, though!